# Send Message via GmailService API auto-wraps lines

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

This is an odd one.

I'm using MimeKit to create a TEXT (not html) message and then using this

```
public static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
        }
```

To get the base 64 encoded message so that I can send it via gmailService.Users.Messages.Send..

The message goes through - however, in gmail (and other clients) its wrapping the text (inserting auto br)

So, if I decode the base64 before the send., its like this

> Thank you for your feedback !  As I said , I am here to get you into
> your best product blah blah blah

however, in gmail, it comes out like

> Thank you for your feedback !  As I said , I am here to
>
> get you into your best product blah blah blah

Hopefully this shows up correctly - but basically its setting a width on that message body, when it shouldn't.

From the base64 message decode - i see that it set the following

> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

I cant figure out why gmail is wrapping - is there any something I need to set for it to not wrap?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it looks like the newest version of the Gmail .NET SDK (1.34+) doesn't appear to have this issue. That's the only item I've updated in my chain (using it with MimeKit 1.10.1, which is somewhat old now) and this appears to no longer be an issue on my end.